# How to pass options to diff command when using diff3

Tags: git, bash, command-line, compare, diff

`diff` supports options that are not supported by `diff3` on macOS Sierra. For example, `diff` supports `-b` option to ignore white space changes but `diff3` does not.

However, `diff3` supports option `--diff-program` which I suppose can be used to pass a program that will invoke `diff` with the desired options.

As such, I created a program `mydiff` like this:

```
diff -b $1 $2
```

but when running `diff3 --diff-program=./mydiff left.txt base.txt right.txt` on the command line, I got the following error:

```
diff: missing operand after `--'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
diff3: subsidiary program `./mydiff' failed
```

How can this be solved?

Is there a way to avoid creating `mydiff` and pass the options directly in the command line by setting `--diff-program=...` somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `diff3` will invoke the specified `diff` command with these parameters: `--horizon-lines=100 -- F1 F2` where `F1` and `F2` are file parameters. The way you wrote `mydiff`, when you run `diff3 --diff-program=./mydiff left.txt base.txt right.txt`, this will get executed:

```
diff -b --horizon-lines=100 --
```

If you run this, you get the same errors.

The correct way to write `mydiff`:

```
#!/bin/sh

diff -b "$@"
```

And no, unfortunately there's no way to write `diff -b` somehow inline,
you need to create a dedicated script to make it work with `diff3`.